# No numeric data to plot error appears when trying convert excel table to hierarchical graph

Tags: python, graph, converters, hierarchical-grouping

When trying to convert table from excel to graph, I get an error "no numeric data to plot" ["no numeric data to plot"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq7q8.png)
Also, structure of my table is changed not in the right way.
After `self.dataFrame = index.to_frame(index=False)` table is correct

```
|| Test case name |Testing status |Testing status 2023-01-02 |Testing status 2023-02-20 |Testing status 2023-03-15 |
| 0| SW password |PASS | FAILED | FAILED | PASS |
| 1| Access levels |PASS |NOT TESTED |PASS|PASS |
| 2| Local license server|NOT TESTED | NOT TESTED |PASS |PASS |
| 3| High level security  |NOT TESTED |PASS |PASS|PASS|
| 4| Interruption in communication  |FAILED|PASS |PASS|PASS|
| 5| Writing parameters  |FAILED | FAILED |FAILED | FAILED |
```

But at the end of program I have a table which seems incorrect, as on Y axis should be "test case name", on X axis - status.

[Table to draw graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7jR.png)

As a final result I'm trying to convert my excel table to the graph like this [final graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwC3b.png)

When excel contained only two columns (for X and Y axes), command `self.dataFrame = self.dataFrame.groupby(["Test case name", 'Testing status']).count()` worked and graph was drawn correctly. But when few more columns were added - this logic was not working anymore.
Tried following commands and suggestions to solve problem, but all of them return "no numeric data to plot" error:

`self.dataFrame = self.dataFrame.loc[:, [True if re.findall('Testing status+',column) else False for column in self.dataFrame.columns]] #Sort by all clomuns with "Testing status" name`
`testing_status = self.dataFrame.loc[:, [True if re.findall('Testing status+',column) else False for column in self.dataFrame.columns]]`
`self.dataFrame = self.dataFrame.groupby(['Test case name', 'Testing status+']).size())`
Also, `pd.to_numeric` return error "Unable to parse string "SW password" at position 0
[to_numeric error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgse1.png)

Code now looks like this:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("form.ui",self)

        self.uploadButton.clicked.connect(self.load_to_convert_file)
        self.graphButton.clicked.connect(self.convert_to_graph)
        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.save_graph_to_excel_sheet)

    def load_to_convert_file(self):
        """Load excel file"""
        # Get File path as string            
       file, _filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName( parent= self,directory= os.getcwd(), filter= "Excel Files (*.xlsx)")
       self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(self.file)

        try:
            self.df = pd.read_excel(self.file, sheet_name="Checklist", engine="openpyxl", header=[10])
            print(self.df)
            self.loadlabel.setText("Success!")
        except:
            print("Error")
            self.loadlabel.setText("Error loading file.")

    def add_line(self, ax, xpos, ypos):
        """Configuring graph - adding small lines"""
        line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos], transform=ax.transAxes, color='black')
        line.set_clip_on(False)
        ax.add_line(line)

    def label_length(self, my_index, level):
        """Configuring graph - setting label length"""
        labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
        return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]
    
    def label_group_bar_table(self, ax, df):
        """Configuring graph"""
        ypos = -.1
        scale = 1./df.index.size
        for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
            pos = 0
            for label, rpos in self.label_length(df.index, level):
                lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
                ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
                self.add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
                pos += rpos
            self.add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
            ypos -= .1
    
    def convert_to_graph(self):
        """Convert uploaded file to the graph (generic)"""
        try:
            #Copy original file before any actions with same name
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(self.file)
            self.result_file_name = f"{name}_converted{ext}"            
            shutil.copy(self.file, self.result_file_name)
            print("File copied successfully!")
                                                      
            #Group data by time stamp and test case using MultiIndex from DataFrame 
            index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(self.df)                    
            print(index)
                
            # Create a DataFrame object
            self.dataFrame = index.to_frame(index=False)
            print(self.dataFrame)

            
            """Ploting graph"""
            # unstack last level to plot two separate columns
            self.dataFrame = self.dataFrame.unstack(level=-1)
           
            figure = plt.figure() 
            ax = figure.add_subplot(111)

            #Convert data to non numerical and plot graph   
            self.dataFrame = pd.to_numeric(self.dataFrame)            
            self.dataFrame.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=figure.gca())
            
            ax.set_xticklabels('')
            ax.set_xlabel('')
            self.label_group_bar_table(ax, self.dataFrame)
            figure.subplots_adjust(bottom=.1*self.dataFrame.index.nlevels)
             
            plt.title("General state")            
            plt.show(block=True) 
           
        except:
            print("Error to convert!")

   if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Launch programm"""
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.setWindowTitle("Converter table to graph")
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```